# Generate Tibble / DataFrame Code

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

**Question**

I recall, but cannot seem to find, a built-in function that allows you to generate the *code* for creating a tibble / dataframe from an existing tibble / dataframe.

In other words, suppose I have the standard `iris` dataframe. I would like to generate the code to build this dataframe manually.  The function I am looking for would produce something like the following:

```
# Function Call    
Theoretical_Function_I_Recall_Exists_But_Cant_Find(iris)

# Output of Function
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width, ~Petal.Length, ~Petal.Width, ~Species,
      5.1,                    3.5,           1.4,          0.2, "setosa",
      4.9,                    3.0,           1.4,          0.2, "setosa",
      4.7,                    3.2,           1.3,          0.2, "setosa",
      4.6,                    3.1,           1.5,          0.2, "setosa",
      5.0,                    3.6,           1.4,          0.2, "setosa"
    )
```

I could swear that a function to do this already exists, but multiple forays into the help docs and Google have come up empty ...

Anyone recall if such a function actually exists?

Comment: [`deparse::deparse.data.frame`](https://github.com/krlmlr/deparse/blob/master/R/deparse-data-frame.R)

Comment: Maybe also `dput`.

Answer (score 2):

`dput` works well here - also part of base R too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want explicitly `tribble` code, you can use `timesaveR::to_tribble`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for either `datapasta::dpasta()` or `datapasta::dmdclip()`. [datapasta](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta)